# How to reference cells with specific condition in php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got an array like this:

```
$array[0][name]   = "Axel";
$array[0][car]  =     "Pratzner";
$array[0][color]   = "black";

$array[1][name]   = "John";
$array[1][car]  =     "BMW";
$array[1][color]   = "black";

$array[2][name]   = "Peggy";
$array[2][car]  =     "VW";
$array[2][color]   = "white";
```

I would like to do something like "get all `names` WHERE `car = bmw` AND `color = white`"

Could anyone give advice on how the PHP spell would look like?

Comment: every time you have to deal with array, **a loop** is a solution

Comment: BTW, your question title contradicts with the body

Comment: Use `database` and `sql` query :-)

Comment: create a function and let it make doing it `function nameoncondtions($color,$car){                            foreach ($array as $value) {
    if($value["color"]== $color && $value["car"]==$car) return $value["name"];
}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getWhiteBMWs($array) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $entry) {
        if ($entry['car'] == 'bmw' && $entry['color'] == 'white')
            $result[] = $entry;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Edited:** This is a more general solution:

```
// Filter an array using the given filter array
function multiFilter($array, $filters) {
    $result = $array;

    // Removes entries that don't pass the filter
    $fn = function($entry, $index, $filter) {
        $key = $filter['key'];
        $value = $filter['value'];
        $result = &$filter['array'];

        if ($entry[$key] != $value)
            unset($result[$index]);
    };

    foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
        // Pack the filter data to be passed into array_walk
        $filter = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value, 'array' => &$result);

        // For every entry, run the function $fn and pass in the filter data
        array_walk($result, $fn, $filter);
    }

    return array_values($result);
}

// Build a filter array - an entry passes this filter if every
// key in this array corresponds to the same value in the entry.
$filter = array('car' => 'BMW', 'color' => 'white');

// multiFilter searches $array, returning a result array that contains
// only the entries that pass the filter. In this case, only entries
// where $entry['car'] = 'BMW' AND $entry['color'] = 'white' will be
// returned.
$whiteBMWs = multiFilter($array, $filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in code is more or less emulating what a RDBMS is perfect for. Something like this would work:

```
function getNamesByCarAndColor($array,$color,$car) { 
    $matches = array();
    foreach ($array as $entry) { 
        if($entry["color"]== $color && $entry["car"]==$car) 
           matches[] = $entry["name"]; 
    }
    return $matches;
}
```

This code would work well for smaller arrays, but as they got larger and larger it would be obvious that this isn't a great solution and an indexed solution would be much cleaner.